# How do I get excel into python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Help! I'm trying to get excel into my program but I can't figure it out. Can someone suggest a way to do this. I have tried to figure out how to use Tktables, but because I'm doing this at school we don't have all the packs.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: What did you do so far? What error do you get?

Comment: I think you're looking for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) Python's library. You can use its `read_excel` function to get the excel file loaded as a `pandas.DataFrame`. Example: `pandas.read_excel("file.xlsx")`.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I am unsure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are at school, one way to use built in functionality is to save the excel file as a .csv and then use the built in csv package to read what you need into python.

csv is easy to use and described here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html